# How to use a hook on page load and recall after a function call?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-custom-hooks

I am using a hook from an SDK on page load that looks like this:

```
import { useOwnedAssets } from 'somesdk/react'
const { data, isLoading, error } = useOwnedAssets(foo, bar)
```

I call a function `updateAssets()` which affects the owned assets.

How can I call the hook on component load and reevaluate or recall the `useOwnedAssets` hook at the end of the `updateAssets()` function?

For component load I simply use:

```
const { data: ownedNFTs, isLoading, error } = useOwnedAssets(foo, bar)
```

but how to also call after calling updateAssets?

Comment: Maybe export a `setData` function as well?

Comment: It's an imported hook from an sdk

Comment: Can you provide a link to documentation for to the hook?

Comment: https://portal.thirdweb.com/react/react.useownednfts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this library uses `@tanstack/react-query` behind the scenes to manage http calls. You should be able to destructure the refetch function from the `useOwnedNFTs` hook and use that to refetch the data.

You should be able to do this:

```
                                             v
const { data: ownedNFTs, isLoading, error, refetch } = useOwnedAssets(foo, bar)
```

You can check out the docs for the useQuery hook from react-query which is what the useOwnedNFTs hook behind the scenes is. https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useQuery